# Infopath print preview using Calculated field

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, infopath-forms-services

I have a sharepoint infopath form and tried creating the Print preview page of the form.I used the calculated value field in all  the fields. In the multiple selection List box I usedbelow XPath to list all the selected options.

```
substring(eval(eval(incidentSourceList[. != ""], 'concat(., ", ")'), ".."), 0, string-length(eval(eval(incidentSourceList[. != ""], 'concat(., ", ")'), "..")) - 1)
```

So my print preview page looks perfect
[image]

But when we submit the form we see the error like
[image]
I am not sure where exactly is the error. Can anybody help me with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a limitation on using Web form rather than Filler form but you can check this post if it will help you:

http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/mel_balsamo/archive/2013/01/14/get-rid-of-that-quot-control-binding-is-not-supported-quot-error-on-your-design-checker.aspx

It has the same error and it has a workaround solution. There's also a link there where a manual solution (editing the source) is used.